# Perforce equivalent for git add patch?

Tags: git, diff, perforce, git-add

`git add --patch` is very important to me. It shows all the diff chunks, and I say "yes" or "no" to add them to the index, from which I commit. In particular if I added something like a `console.log` in some random file, it won't be picked up in my commit.

For perforce I haven't found anything similar. Nothing as expressive as git.

Is there a good workflow or solution?

Comment: Use git. Then write a script to check your git master into perforce. Perhaps add support to your script for other branches. I know there's [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) and git-cvs, so it's possible to write hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-p4](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) to interact with the Perforce repository using Git.  [Even the Perforce folks think its a good idea](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120113/git-perforce-client)!